# How to get Twitter usernames using Tweepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I have a list (json file) containing Twitter account ID downloaded from my Twitter account, I was wondering if there was a way to use Tweepy to get the usernames (@handle) associated with those accountid?

I am a noob when it comes to using python and would appreciate as much hand holding as I could get as to how to go by it.

Answer (score 0):

There's Tweepy API v1.1 and Tweepy API v2, for better inclusiveness we can use Tweepy API v2 for this, as it does not require Elevated Access.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74747452/19469824) shows an authentication example for Tweepy API v2 using the `tweepy.Client` class seen in the [Tweepy API docs](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html?#tweepy.Client) with tokens and keys which can be obtained from the [Twitter Developer Portal.](https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/dashboard)

Once we have the authentication set, we can use the `get_user` method seen in the [API docs here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html?#tweepy.Client.get_user) and the most important parameter here is the id parameter for the input, so that we can convert it into its respective username. We do this by calling `user_get.data.username`. You can look up all of its response fields [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/lookup/api-reference/get-users-id#tab1).

With this you can iterate your JSON file however you want and print the usernames given a twitter id.

Here's an example that prints 3 Twitter IDs as their usernames:

```
import tweepy

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token="YOUR_BEARER_KEY",
                   consumer_key="YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY",
                   consumer_secret="YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET",
                   access_token="YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN",
                   access_token_secret="YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET")

twitterIdList = [3255900970, 432180172, 74274804]
for id in twitterIdList:
    user_get = client.get_user(id=id)
    user_name = user_get.data.username
    print(user_name)
```